# Determine if child of <div> is &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check whether the contents of a div are either `&nbsp;` or more `<div>`'s and such.

I thought maybe I could do this like $('#right-rail').content or $('#right-rail').value or even $('#right-rail').children(), but it doesn't seem to work.

All I get is either "undefined" or "[object Object]".

Thanks for any help I can get :).

PS, using jQuery if you hadn't guessed by now.

Comment: `$('#right-rail').innerHTML=="&nbsp;"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#right-rail').html()` returns the raw content of `#right-rail`

Comment: `.html()` is the jQuery version of `.innerHTML`, I think. Yes, that should work.

Comment: What I ended up doing was the following: if($('#right-rail').is(':parent')){ whatever } else { whatever }