# nbsp added to string when copied from excel sheet

Tags: javascript

When i copy a string with multiple non breaking spaces from my mail to excel sheet and then to my a text box in my site, an nbsp is added to it which gives error while parsing it to xml.How can i check it using javascript?

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787592/determine-if-child-of-div-is-nbsp may be usefull

Comment: @manish, As I understand, the OP wants to clear the extra space from the variable. Unless I got it wrong and he actually wants to literally check for the characters nbsp

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the start of your script

```
String.prototype.trim = function()
{
   return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

and use it like this

```
var theString = ' a string ';
var theStringWithNoSpaces = theString.trim(); 
//Removes the spaces at the start and end, but not the space in the middle of 'a' and 'string'
```

If you're using jquery, that method is built in. Simply use

```
var theString = ' a string ';
var theStringWithNoSpaces = $.trim(theString);
```